# Unable to access SQL Server database under security context

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2, windows-authentication

I am trying to store Windows Account information in my database. I created the database as usual and ran aspnet_regsql.exe. I get the following error after choosing "Windows Authentication" and entering the correct server and database:

The SQL error number is 916 and the SqlException message is: The server principal "" is not able to access the database "" under the current security context.

Having searched for a solution, I have already gone in on SQL Server Management Studio 2008-R2 and unchecked Collation, as this seemed to be a problem for others with my same error. However, I am still getting the same error.

Any advice on what to do?

Comment: I can get regsql to work just fine for forms authentication, so I know it's not an issue with my server name.

Comment: What user context is the command prompt running under? More than likely you need to run the prompt under the context of a user authorized to make changes to the SQL server.

Comment: I also tried "autoclose=false", but that did not work either.

Comment: I only have sysadmin privileges according to the sql server. Would I need to have serveradmin as well in order to make this work?

Comment: @FrazellThomas I ran it as an administrator, but I still had the same problem. As far as I can tell, with current sysadmin privileges, I should be able to perform this operation.